# How to fix Unexpected end of file (kaboom.js)

Tags: javascript, kaboom

I'm getting an error saying unexpected end of file.
Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: make the file longer?

Comment: my guess is there is a rogue quotation mark somewhere in your code, are you using a linter of any kind?

Comment: @NoncomissionedRush i'm not using a linter...